# Call function across classes through controller

Tags: php, oop, controller

I have this controller class.

```
<?php

class controller{

function __construct(){
    $this->db       = new db;
    $this->output   = new output;
}

}

class db{
    function get(){
        return 'value from db';
    }

}

class output{
    function view(){
        print $controller->$db->get();
    }

}
$c  = new controller;
$c->output->view();
?>
```

Ofcourse this is not working, but i think it gets across the idea of what i'm trying to do. How should i do this?

Comment: have you installed the php extension?

Comment: I think you need to look at design patterns, specifically MVC. This is an arse-over-tit way of displaying content in a view, from a data source, via a controller.

Comment: Can you give me a quick explanation of how to do this or a good tutorial about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

class controller{

function control($db, $output){
    $data = $db->get();
    $output->view($data);
}

}

class db{
    function get(){
        return 'value from db';
    }

}

class output{
    function view($data){
        print $data;
    }

}
$db = new db;
$output = new output;
$c = new controller;
$c->control($db, $output);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This however was just an example.

the amount of 'subfunction' are determined from a function of the controller, so this won't work.

Comment: @user3053216 I don't quite understand what you mean. Of course you'll have more models and views. For each page you should have a separate, localized controller that extends the main controller.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use PHP5 Type Hinting. You can read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php)

Code:

```
<?php

class controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->db         = new db;
        $this->output    = new output($this->db);
    }

}
class db
{
    function get()
    {
        return 'value from db';
    }
}

class output
{
    private $_db;

    public function __construct(db $get)
    {
        $this->_db = $get->get();
    }

    public function view() {
        return $this->_db;
    }
}

$c  = new controller();
echo $c->output->view();
```

In this example:

We're type hinting the class of `db` passing the `$this->db` instantiated object to the `controller` class `__construct` magic method.

And then on `output` class we're passing the actual classname `db` with instantiated variable and getting the method `get()` and storing the value to the private `$db_` property and returning to `view()` method.

Hope it helps!